# atal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class

Tags: swift, react-native

I'm working on a react native app that requires a library that's available only in native, so I'm working on bridging swift and react native, I think everything will work if I solve this problem.

Every time I run the app, I get an error saying:
`Reader.swift:7: Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init()' for class`

I tried all many solutions given in other stack overflow articles, but could not find a solution to this yet

Any help given would be appreciated

Thanks

Here is the code for the class:

```
class TextBookDataHolderImpl: NSObject, TextBookDataHolder {
  var book: Book
  
  init(book: Book) {
      self.book = book
  }
}
```

Comment: So you are calling an initializer that doesn’t exist, read the documentation (or code) for that class and use a different one when creating an object at line 7.

Comment: I added my code to the question, could you please explain this in more detail

Comment: How can you not see it? There is no `init()`, only an `init(book: Book)`. Either add an `init` without parameters or change the code in Reader.swift

Comment: First, the code above is the Reader.swift file and second if I add an empty init function it shows an error saying: Overriding declaration requires an 'override' keyword

Comment: Then which one is line 7 that generates the error?

Comment: const init = (book: Book) => {'your code here'}

Comment: @Flávio Costa your solution gives another error that says: Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'

Comment: @Joakim Danielson, Line 7 is the line where I'm declaring the class

Comment: const init = (book: Book) => {self.book = book};

Comment: @Flávio Costa I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: can you add a snapcode?

Comment: What's a snapcode????